# Evaluate term in Prolog and write it

Tags: prolog, output, stdout, evaluation

Hi I am learning prolog (using swi-prolog 7 on Mac) but I cannot find enough docs/tutorials to explain how to print out a result of a term evaluation. I tried code below but it always prints out `ERROR: prolog/test.pl:2: user:main: false` for any arguments.

```
#!/usr/bin/env swipl
:- initialization(main, main).

fun1(A, B):- A < B.
fun2([A1 | A2]):- A3 is fun1(A1, A2), write(A3).

main(args) :- fun2(args).
```

How can I write result of `fun1` to stdout in SWI-Prolog?

Comment: What is `A3` supposed to be?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem A3 is purely for sake of output, at least that was my plan

Comment: As a beginner do not, repeat do not write or print yourself. Instead, use the [tag:prolog-toplevel] instead. Type `X is 1+1.` to see how the answer is printed automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
fun1(A,B,Value) :-
    (
        A < B
    ->
        Value = true
    ;
        Value = false
    ).

fun2(A1,A2) :-
    fun1(A1, A2, Value ),
    format('Result: ~w~n',[Value]).
```

Example run:

```
?- fun2(1,2).
Result: true
true.
```

In Prolog you have to think of the result of each line as being true or false and then possibly binding a value to a variable or something more complex as state.

The code in the question was returning that the predicate was true or false but not binding a value to a variable or altering state. By adding `Value` as an additional parameter and then binding a value in the predicate, the value in `Value` was able to be used for display.

---

**EDIT**

Question from OP in comment

> I have never seen `->` is it documented somewhere? Sorry if it is a noobie question.

No it is not a noobie question, and actually it was wise of you to just ask instead of festering on it.

See: [Control Predicates](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=control)

In particular [->/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(-%3E)/2) or (`:Condition -> :Action`) is often used with [;/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3B)/2) and together they work like an `if then else`, e.g.

> `if then else` syntax:

NB This is not Prolog syntax but a syntax common in many [imperative programming languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming).

```
if (<condition>) then
  <when true>
else
  <when false>
```

> `-> ;` syntax:

This is Prolog syntax.

```
(
   <condition>
->
   <when true>
;
   <when false>
)
```

---

**EDIT**

Question from OP in comment

> When I run this code without the init block and main, so just in interactive mode, then it works. When I try to make a script out of it I get the same error `ERROR: prolog/test.pl:2: user:main: false`

First

```
main(args) :- fun2(args).
```

`args` is a value but needs to be a variable and in Prolog variables by default start with a capital letter.

```
main(Args) :- fun2(Args).
```

Next, Args as received in `main/1` is a list, but `fun2/2` expects two separate parameters. So by deconstructing `Args` into a list of two items with `Args = [A1,A2]` the items in the list can be used as individual items to be passed as parameters to `fun2/2`.

```
main(Args) :-
    Args = [A1,A2],
    fun2(A1,A2).
```

Example run from top level.

```
?- main([1,2]).
Result: true
true.
```

I  leave it as an exercise to check if this works as needed from the command line.

Comment: thanks! I have never seen `->` is it documented somewhere? Sorry if it is a noobie question..

Comment: when I run this code without the init block and main, so just in interactive mode, then it works. When I try to make a script out of it I get the same error `ERROR: prolog/test.pl:2: user:main: false` but this is probably a separate question that I need to figure out ... Thanks!